# Upload Multiple Files to S3 using Low Level S3 API (PutObjectRequest)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am fairly new to AWS and .NET and I am trying to check the performance of PutObjectRequest against Transfer Utility across various data sizes and parameters. I want to upload 10 files using both the APIs and compare the timings.

This is something I tried

```
DirectoryInfo place = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Files\256KB");
FileInfo[] Files = place.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
var str = file.Name;
string destinationPath = Path.Combine(directoryName, str);
if (destinationPath.Length > 0)
 {
   var s3LocationForUploadData = "uploadir";
   PutObject(destinationPath, s3LocationForUploadData);
 }
}


public void PutObject(string filePathStreamToSave, string objectKeyForFile)
{
try
{
 
 var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
 {
 BucketName = Bucket,
 Key = objectKeyForFile,
 FilePath = filePathStreamToSave  
 };

 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine("TIME ELAPSED:"+sw.Elapsed);
 Console.ReadLine();
 }

 catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object",e.Message);
 }
 }
```

However the PutObject call inside the foreach gets executed only once. Any idea how I would achieve to trigger the PutObjectAsync call for each of the 10 files?

Comment: `PutObject call inside the foreach gets executed only once` how do you confirm this?

Comment: @Chetan I ran the program and I see that only the first file out of the 10 present in the directory is uploaded to S3.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` you have this code in `PutObject` method. This line will stop the code execution and wait for an input to the console. Is this intended? `"TIME ELAPSED:"` do you see 10 such messages in the console?

Comment: Removal of Console.ReadLine() worked, and now I could see 10 iterations of the TIME ELAPSED message on console. Thank you!